# Getting the JavaMail API to Work... Again

Tags: email, jakarta-mail, java

I'm working on an application that uses the JavaMail API to send an email, but I keep getting errors. I'm using Eclipse to code it and I'm using gmail to send it. I took out my real password for obvious reasons so you're probably going to need to replace that with your own if you need to experiment. Now that I've fixed some stuff thanks to you guys, I think I'm getting a timeout error because it takes a long time until it displays the error, but beyond that much, I haven't the foggiest clue. Thanks in advance for any help or advice once more.

Code:

```
package com.brighamcampbell.sunrisegundersonmail;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Properties;  

import javax.mail.*;  
import javax.mail.internet.*;  

public class Mail {  

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException,
    UnsupportedEncodingException {

Properties mailProps = new Properties();

mailProps.put("mail.smtp.from", "butterscotchdreamer23@gmail.com");
mailProps.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
mailProps.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
mailProps.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
mailProps.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
mailProps.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(mailProps, new Authenticator() {


    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication("butterscotchdreamer23@gmail.com", "password");
    }

});


MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

//set the email sender
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("butterscotchdreamer23@gmail.com"));

//set the email recipients
String[] emails = { "butterscotchdreamer23@gmail.com" };

InternetAddress dests[] = new InternetAddress[emails.length];
for (int i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
    dests[i] = new InternetAddress(emails[i].trim().toLowerCase());
}
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, dests);

//set the email subject
message.setSubject("test");

//set the email content
message.setText("this is a test");

//send
System.out.println("sending...");
Transport.send(message);
System.out.println("done sending email!");

}
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465, response: -1
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2041)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:697)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:386)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:194)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at com.brighamcampbell.sunrisegundersonmail.Mail.main(Mail.java:56)
```

Thanks for the patience!

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the mail server doesn't support STARTTLS, so you shouldn't enable it.

Comment: GMail does, and certainly used to require it

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the 3 sslfactory properties as it is not needed anymore for javamail.You should be able to connect that way.

Note:The gmail server definitely support STARTTLS:

> ```
> x@test:~/$ telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
> Trying 74.125.136.108...
> Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
> Escape character is '^]'.
> 220 mx.google.com ESMTP vv9sm12826892wjc.35 - gsmtp
> EHLO me
> 250-mx.google.com at your service, [147.58.51.121]
> 250-SIZE 35882577
> 250-8BITMIME
> 250-STARTTLS
> 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
> 250-PIPELINING
> 250-CHUNKING
> 250 SMTPUTF8
> QUIT
> ```

Answer (score 0):

General Gmail instructions are [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail), general connection debugging tips are [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug), and a list of common mistakes is [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  Possibly you're running into a firewall or anti-virus program that's intercepting your attempt to connect.  If you still can't make it work, post the JavaMail debug output.